# How to set space between TableRows in JavaFX TableView?

Tags: java, css, user-interface, javafx, tableview

Is it possible to set some space between `TableRows`? There is no `VGap` option and of course setting margins in `JavaFX` with `CSS` also doesn't work.

Does anybody got a solution for my problem?

Thank you!

Comment: have tried border-spacing ? it can take 2 value for horizontal and vertical spacing. It works with html table or any layout using the display:table; layout. for flex, margin will do and for grid, margin or grid-gap caould help too.

Comment: yes ... and how did you come to the conclusion _of course setting margins with css doesn't work_ Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and act accordingly.

Comment: @G-Cyr Unfortunately there is no `border-spacing` or `-fx-border-spacing` property in JavaFx... Many standard CSS features aren't available here.

Comment: @kleopatra There is also no property for setting margins with css. There are only few JavaFx elements that allow margins – but not with css. For JavaFx TableRows this is simply not possible.

Comment: it's just not called "margin" - the effect of border properties is near enough, or not?