# How to set space between rows in a JavaFX TreeTableView?

Tags: javafx

I'm trying to allow 5 pixels of space between rows on a JavaFX TreeTableView. I figured that changing the margin, padding, or border width on one of the CSS elements would fix it, but either nothing happens or the text in the table cell is moved around.

I see that there might be solutions for TreeViews and TableViews, like the StackOverflow link below, but they don't appear to apply to TreeTableViews.

[How to set space between TableRows in JavaFX TableView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51540312/how-to-set-space-between-tablerows-in-javafx-tableview)

My Current CSS:

```
.tree-table-view {
    -fx-table-cell-border-color: transparent;
    -fx-background-color: black;
}

/* TreeTableView */
.tree-table-view .column-header,
.tree-table-view .column-header-background .filler {
    -fx-background-color: black;
    -fx-border-width: 100;
}

.tree-table-cell{
    -fx-text-fill: white;
    -fx-wrap-text: true;
}

.tree-table-row-cell .tree-disclosure-node .arrow {
    -fx-shape: null;
    -fx-background-color: null;

    -fx-min-width: 0;
    -fx-pref-width: 0;
    -fx-max-width: 0;

    -fx-min-height: 0;
    -fx-pref-height: 0;
    -fx-max-height: 0;
}

.tree-table-row-cell:expanded .tree-disclosure-node .arrow {
    -fx-shape: null;
    -fx-background-color: null;
    -fx-max-width: 0;
    -fx-max-height: 0;
}

.tree-table-row-cell{
    -fx-background-color: black;
    -fx-font-size: 12px;
    -fx-indent: 0;
    -fx-cell-size: 50px;
}

.group-tree-table-row-cell{
    -fx-background-color: darkgray;
}

.entry-tree-table-row-cell{
    -fx-background-color: darkslategray;
}

.tree-table-row-cell:selected{
    -fx-background-color: darkblue;

    -fx-table-cell-border-color: transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to apply your style to the `tree-table-cell` style class (Documentation can be found here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#treetablecell)

Applying a border width of 5 at the bottom of each cell in a column can give you the desired effect without shifting the text. This can be done by adding the following to your style sheet.

```
.tree-table-cell {
    -fx-border-width: 0 0 5 0;
}
```

This can also be done by setting a custom cell factory for columns of the `TreeTableView` and providing the cells with the desired settings. See `TreeTableColumn#setCellFactory(Callback<TreeTableColumn<S,T>,TreeTableCell<S,T>> value`https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TreeTableColumn.html#setCellFactory-javafx.util.Callback-).